# Link to a dynamic link library in a cmake project

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

In a first step I created a `test.dll` library with the corresponding import library `test.dll.a` and the header file `test.h`. I build a new "client" project where I want to use this created library.

I have the following file structure:

```
client
│ └── CMakeLists.txt
|── src
│ ├── main.cpp
│ └── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│ ├── test.dll
│ └── libtest.dll.a
│ └── test.h
```

In the root `CmakeLists.txt` I wanted to add the library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(client)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_library(test SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(
       test
       PROPERTIES
           IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/client/lib/test.dll
           IMPORTED_IMPLIB /path/client/lib/libtest.dll.a 
)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

And in the src `CmakeLists.txt` file I wrote:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE test)
```

In the client `main.cpp` I included the library via `#include "test.h"`.

With that I get the error message: `test.h: No such file or directory` and `cannot open source file test.h`.

Does somebody know how to add the DLL correctly to the cmake project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` need to be added to the test target.

```
set_target_properties(
       test
       PROPERTIES
           INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /path/client/lib
           IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/client/lib/test.dll
           IMPORTED_IMPLIB /path/client/lib/libtest.dll.a 
)
```

NB: The `add_subdirectory(lib)` command can be safely removed, as you did not place a CMakeLists.txt file there and nothing needs to be built inside this dir.